# Sorting algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Write a JavaScript callback for the jQuery function `$("#sort").click`. Allow the user to enter three numbers in any order. Output the numbers in order from lowest to highest.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sort").click(function() {
    var a = Number($("#a").val());
    var b = Number($("#b").val());
    var c = Number($("#c").val());
    var message = "";
   if (b > c) {
     if ((b + c) > (a + c)) {
       message = c + " " + a + " " + b;
     } else {
       message = c + " " + b + " " + a;
     }
   } else {
     message = b + " " + a + " " + c;
   }
    if (b > a) {
      if ((a + b) > (a + c)) {
        message = a + " " + c + " " + b;
      } else {
        message = a + " " + b + " " + c;
      }
    } else {
      message = b + " " + c + " " + a;
    }
  $("#output").html(message)
  });
});
```

Would anyone mind looking at this code and saying what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that you can only use five comparisons.

Comment: What majes you think that "it's wrong"?

Comment: given his constraints for only using five comparisons, this is probably a lesson of some kind

Comment: Is the output different than what you expect or why do you think that there is something wrong? We have a close reason for this kind of question, which reads *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Comment: In your example, you're manually checking for every possible permutation, instead of letting the computer work for you. Why not just use Array.sort()?

Comment: Why are you comparing sums to each other, instead of just the numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Some great jQuery answers here, I'll cover the comparisons part.

You don't need five comparisons, just three (or two if you're lucky). Compare `a` and `b`, and swap them if `a > b`. Then compare `c` and `b`. If `c > b`, you're done, otherwise compare `c` and `a`:

```
if (a > b)
  x = a, a = b, b = x;

if (c < b)
  if (c < a)
    result = [c, a, b];
  else
    result = [a, c, b];
else
  result = [a, b, c];
```

If all numbers are 32-bit positive ints, you can sort them without any comparisons at all:

```
min = function(a,b) { return b + ((a-b) & ((a-b)>>31)) }
max = function(a,b) { return a - ((a-b) & ((a-b)>>31)) }

x = min(a, min(b, c));
z = max(a, max(b, c));
y = (a + b + c) - (x + z);

result = [x, y, z];
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with the code is that it isn't well organized.
Instead of using nested if statements to manually check every combination of values, try using the tools & methods that are already available to you.

To sort the values, you can put them in an array and call sort() on it.

```
//Function to compare numbers
function compareNumbers(a, b)
{
    return a - b;
}

var a = Number($("#a").val());
var b = Number($("#b").val());
var c = Number($("#c").val());

//let's say a = 2, b = 3, c = 1

var arr = [a,b,c];
//The array arr is now [2,3,1]

arr.sort(compareNumbers);
//The array arr is now [1,2,3]
```

Now you can set the message by grabbing elements from arr in order.

Comment: Major spoiler alert: `Array.sort()`

Comment: Bergi: Whoops! Forgot about that. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is also right, But Better you put all values into an array.

Get All element value and push value into an array, 
Use `array.sort();;`

to Sort numbers (numerically and ascending):

```
arrayname.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

to Sort numbers (numerically and descending):

```
arrayname.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (short) solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sort").click(function () {
        var msg = [$("#a").val(), $("#b").val(), $("#c").val()].sort(
        function (a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });
        alert(msg);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
$("#sort").on("click", function (e) {
    var vals = $.map($("#a, #b, #c"), function (v, k) {
        return Number(v.value)
    })
    , min = null
    , msg = "";
    do {
        min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);
        msg += min;
        vals.splice($.inArray(min, vals), 1)
    } while (vals.length > 0);
    $("output").html(msg)
});
```

```js
    $("#sort").on("click", function (e) {
        var vals = $.map($("#a, #b, #c"), function (v, k) {
            return Number(v.value)
        })
        , min = null
        , msg = "";
        do {
            min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);
            msg += min;
            vals.splice($.inArray(min, vals), 1)
        } while (vals.length > 0);
        $("output").html(msg)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" type="text" value="2" />
<input id="b" type="text" value="7" />
<input id="c" type="text" value="1" />
<button id="sort">click</button>
<br />
<output></output>
```

Comment: Lacks explanation as well as correctness (not even taking the horrible code into account)

Comment: Will update answer with description at comments . If possible , can detail "correctness" ? Thanks

Comment: Well, if you can *reason* that and why it works as expected, it is correct. I bet you cannot.

Comment: @Bergi Not certain about meaning of "_reason_" ? Description of `object` key sorting in js ? Please illuminate errors at piece / comment description ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, [reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reason#Computer_science). What is "object key sorting"?

Comment: @Bergi Interesting :) See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Examples (third example) , console at http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6jmv526a/5/

Comment: I'm not looking for "examples". There is [no defined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17101063/1048572) [order of keys](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9658712/1048572) (except for "always the same").

Comment: Not exactly certain what "looking for" ? jsfiddle at previous comment , perhaps , visually demonstrates the "re-ordering" of the resultant array returned by `Object.keys()` . The array initially begins with `[2, 7]` , then gets "sorted" to `[1, 2, 7]` when the value `1` gets added as a property of `n` . At first link: _"All JS engines that I tested on return numerical order: "1", "2", "10""_ :)

Comment: "All JS engines that someone tested with a specific example" is by no means a generic reason. In general, you cannot rely on this, and you should not - especially when answering a newbie question.

Comment: Apart from that, there's no reason to do `msg = Object.keys(n).join("");` inside of the loop; and `delete n` is total rubbish.

Comment: @Bergi If possible , can create piece / case where numerical order would _not_ be returned ? given _type_ of input ? Which specific engines would return a _non_-numerical order ? Fair enough at `.join()` . What is issue with `delete` ? , not needed for any further processing at that point , why not call `delete` ?

Comment: @Bergi If answer is _not_ helpful , should remove ? Thanks

Comment: It's *your* piece that might not give numerical order - e.g. in [these browsers](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164#c8).

Comment: The issue with `delete` is a) that you are *using* `n` in the next iteration of the loop b) that [it doesn't work like that](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

Comment: @Bergi Withdrawn (although your comments _are_ helpful as to the question / `Object.keys()` . Should keep post up for your comments ?) . Thanks !

Comment: @Bergi See updated post. Tried with numbers 0-9 . Could add 10-n numbers to `n` for numbers greater than 10 . Thanks

Comment: Um, that's *interesting*. I've never seen anybody use `[].slice.call("0123456789")` - common is `"0123456789".split('')`. The algorithm you use for sorting is creative, but unfortunately slow and works only for a finite set of numbers. It reminds me of radix sort somehow, though.