# input file to array javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an input type file where i put into a variable in javascript where i want to manipulate the files.

HTML:

```
<input class="file" id="file1" name="uploadedimages[]" type='file' multiple/>
```

JavaScript:

```
var upload = document.getElementById('file1');
upload.files.splice(idtoremove,1) //not working
```

how can i delete a specific item in upload variable?.I have search that input type file is a readonly and you cannot manipulate it unless you put it to an array and upload the files with ajax.

im doing this for upload to my gallery. first i select multiple images. then there will be a preview first for the pictures before uploading. there will be also an option to remove a photo. my problem is. how can i delete that photo file in input file. so the possible solution is to store input file to array then delete what photo you want in the array then create a formdata for the array and upload using ajax

Comment: sorry for that. i already edited my question

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez Tried `js` at post ?

Comment: @guest271314 hi, what do you mean sir?.

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez See updated post. Try attaching `change` event to `input` element to access files. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit, Updated

> how can i delete a specific item in upload variable?

If expected result is array of file objects would adjust approach to splicing array items from original `files` object - and sending spliced array as upload - instead of attempting to "delete" items from original `files` object *and* still uploading original `files` object.

---

[FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object does not have `.splice()` method . Try utilizing `.slice()` , `.call()` to convert `files` to `Array` , then call `.splice()` method on array of `File` objects, e.g.;

```
// `_files` : `File` object items from original `files` `FileList`
// call `.splice()` on items that would be uploaded ,
// upload `_files` array - _not_ original `files` `FileList` object
// e.g.; `_files`:`File` objects to _keep_ not "delete" from `files`
var idstokeep = [0, 2]; // splice , keep first `2` files 
var _files = Array.prototype.slice.call(files).splice(idstokeep[0], idstokeep[1]);
```

See [how does Array.prototype.slice.call() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056925/how-does-array-prototype-slice-call-work/)

---

Alternatively , utilize

> [item()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList#item)
>
> Returns a File object representing the file at the
>   specified index in the file list.

to return files at specific `index` within `FileList`

```
  var files = e.target.files;
  // return `file` at `index` `1`
  var firstFile = files.item(1);
```

---

```js
var upload = document.getElementById("file1");

upload.onchange = function(e) {
  var files = e.target.files;
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList#item
  var firstFile = files.item(1); 
  var idstokeep = [0, 2]; // keep first `2` files from `multiple` selection
  var _files = Array.prototype.slice.call(files).splice(idstokeep[0], idstokeep[1]);
  console.log(files, files.length         
              , _files, _files.length
              , firstFile);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input class="file" id="file1" name="uploadedimages[]" type='file' multiple/>
```

Comment: @guest271314 I hope OP will say something in the comments of your answer, because otherwise we spend our time for nothing. As I understood, OP wants to change `upload.files` object (`FileList`) by removing one item from this list. _removing from list_ does mean that **original** object is changed, not its modified version elsewhere. As one of the results of this action you should see "2 files are selected" instead of "3 files are selected" in the default `<input type="file">` info. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0gous4vv/3/) illustrates what is required. But it doesn't work due to readonly.

Comment: @Regent Yes. Updated post attempts approach of utilizing `.splice()` to create "new" array of file objects to "keep" , _not_ attempting to modify, "delete" , or upload original `FileList` object. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245482/sorting-algorithm-in-javascript/26246038#comment41172485_26246038

Comment: @Regent Instead of `splice()` , could utilize `files.item(index)` within loop to return, upload desired files ? , if expected result at endpoint is `File` object , and not `Array` ? See updated stacksnippets .

Comment: @guest271314 you can iterate through selected files with `upload.files.item(index)` or with `upload.files[index]`, but neither `upload.files[1] = { };` nor `delete upload.files[1]` works, because of readonly status of `upload.files`.

Comment: @Regent and guest271314. im doing this for upload to my gallery. first i select multiple images. then there will be a preview first for the pictures before uploading. there will be also an option to remove a photo. my problem is. how can i delete that photo file in input file. so the possible solution is to store input file to array then delete what photo you want in the array then create a formdata for the array and upload using ajax

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez Yes. Post , stacksnippets attempts to demonstrate possible approaches of selecting which files will be uploaded; including `.splice()` , `.item()`. Alternatively `upload.files[index]` demonstrated by @Regent at comments , jsfiddle. Do solutions provided at Answer resolve Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 i still cant get it. :( my brain is damaged

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez  Can describe _"i still cant get it."_ ? , create  stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle to demonstrate  ? Tried stacksnippets above ?

Comment: @guest271314 how can i upload the _file var which is an array from array.proto.splice...

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez Try creating a `json` object from files properties , converting file to `base64` string. Try selecting three or more files at http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/LL95z474/6 ; should return first two files selected, applying `var idstokeep = [0, 2];` . May require minimal wait for responses depending on file size; see network tab at console during requests.

Comment: @guest271314 how about ajax post only without displaying the images. because i already display them before uploading

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez Can remove `results` variable through to and including next line that appends `results` to `body` element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76345/discussion-between-john-christian-de-chavez-and-guest271314).

Comment: @guest271314 hi, im having trouble in splice. it removes the wrong item after the first remove. i think because of the _files. re organize the indexes. right?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var upload = document.getElementById("file1");

upload.onchange = function(e) {
  var files = e.target.files;
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList#item
  var firstFile = files.item(1); 
  var idstokeep = [0, 2]; // keep first `2` files from `multiple` selection
  var _files = Array.prototype.slice.call(files).splice(idstokeep[0], idstokeep[1]);
  console.log(files, files.length         
              , _files, _files.length
              , firstFile);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input class="file" id="file1" name="uploadedimages[]" type='file' multiple/>
```