# HTML5 Deselect certain files to be uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am creating a mobile web app that will allow users to upload multiple images to the server. I was wondering, in HTML5 (or even JS), is there any way that a user can make changes to the files they have selected before they upload it. For example, suppose I click the input button and choose 20 images and then I would want to remove 2 of these images and add another one. Can this be done? The input field should basically remember what you have selected so that when you press the button again, it already shows you the selected files (to which you can remove or add to)

```
<input type="file" name="browseImages" id="browseImages" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: and what does the input field do if you click the button again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841147/input-file-to-array-javascript-jquery

Comment: @wero It will clear the previously selected files and allow me select new files