# Remove Individual Files When Multiple FIles Are Selected With File Input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove individual files from the list of files to be uploaded when the user is allowed to select multiple files? For example, I have an input that looks somewhat like that:

And the user selects 4 photos, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and 4.jpg. Is it possible to remove 4.jpg, because the user changed their mind and doesn't want to upload that one?

Comment: You can't modify the input.files object. You can however make an editable "copy" of it by storing each file object into an array. Then create some UI to show those files and make the edition of this array possible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841147/input-file-to-array-javascript-jquery/