# How to work with FileList (from <input type="file">) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In [this W3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp), `console.log` on the input element reveals a FileInput object:

```
FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}
```

How can I work with this? The example demonstrates accessing the file, but every time a user selects new files, the old files disappear. How can I create a new empty FileList and copy it over, so that a user can add more files to the FileList?

I tried this, but it results in two FileList objects, rather than one FileList with all the files:

```
var fileStore = x.files;

function myFunction(){
    var txt = "";
    if ('files' in x) {
        if (x.files.length == 0) {
            txt = "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            fileStore += x.files;
            console.log(x.files);
            console.log(fileStore);
```

Comment: FileList has a readonly length, so I'm guessing it cannot be mutated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: Ah alright, in that case I'd like to ask, how can I add those files into another variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Untested, but this should work

```
var fileStore = [];

function myFunction(){
    var txt = "";
    if ('files' in x) {
        if (x.files.length == 0) {
            txt = "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            fileStore.push.apply(fileStore,x.files);
            console.log(x.files);
            console.log(fileStore);
```

[More on Function::apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

[More on Array::push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the docs. I have to wait 6 minutes until it lets me accept an answer.

Comment: best and easiest solution.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to add `File` objects to `FileList`. You can use `FormData` to append `Files` to a single object.

```
var data = new FormData();
document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  for (var i = 0, files = event.target.files; i < files.length; i++) {
    data.append("file-" + [...data.keys()].length, files[i], files[i].name)
  }
})
```

Comment: @DavidTan See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841147/input-file-to-array-javascript-jquery/

Comment: Thanks. This is slightly more complicated but could ultimately prove more usable than a list since FormData has methods for deleting etc.

Comment: @DavidTan `Array.prototype.splice()` can add or remove an item from an array

Answer (score 5):

An array is fine for holding onto the `File` instances, but `FormData` is better if you want to upload them somewhere. If you want to log out or view the FormData, turning it into a `Map` is an option. Keep in mind that `FormData` is iterable.

```
var formData = new FormData();
var index = 0;

function onDrop(event)
{
  var dt = event.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  var count = files.length;
  output("File Count: " + count + "\n");

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {    
    formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
  }
}

function output(text)
{
  document.getElementById("output").textContent += text;
  console.dir(new Map(formData));
}
```

[See this JSBin.](https://jsbin.com/ginoqa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks, the JSBin is much appreciated. An answer is already accepted, but this answer is even more useful for people like myself making a javascript file uploader.

Answer (score 5):

it is possible to add files using the datatransfer class

```
export const makeFileList = files => {
  const reducer = (dataTransfer, file) => {
    dataTransfer.items.add(file);
    return dataTransfer;
  }

  return files.reduce(reducer, new DataTransfer()).files;
}
```