# Update the status of a input[type=file] when change files

Tags: javascript, html

I've this file input:

```
<input type="file" id="fileSelector" multiple="true">
```

If I add or remove files inside this input, it doesn't update its text.

```
fileSelector.files = [];
```

E.g, if its text is "2 files selected" and I change the `files` array, it doesn't update this text.

How to update this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set the value of [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) of `<input type="file">` element `.files` programmatically; `FileList` is read-only

Comment: @nicematt See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841147/input-file-to-array-javascript-jquery/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580177/how-to-work-with-filelist-from-input-type-file-in-javascript/