# Passing Event Data-Transfer files to Other page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, drag-and-drop

I was trying to implement the Drag& Drop of files to the Browser with Following code:

```js
function hello() {
  //document.getElementById("fileSelectorArea").style.background-color=grey;
  document.getElementById("fileSelectorArea").style.opacity=1;
}
function hi() {
  document.getElementById("fileSelectorArea").style.opacity=0.4;
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("FirstLine").style.display="none";
  event.target.style.border = "4px dotted blue";
}


function leavedrag(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("FirstLine").style.display="inline";
  event.target.style.border = "3px dotted grey";
}

function dropHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var files=event.dataTransfer.files;
  var x=files[0].name;
  var DropSize=files.length;
  if(DropSize==1) {

    //appending filehandler to target area and assign files to it---1      
    //IE restriction   
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById("fileDoc"));
    event.target.lastChild.files=files;
    //------------1

    //Browser restriction
    //Assign event Object to FileHandler---2
    var we=document.getElementById("fileSelector");
    we=event.target.lastChild;
    //-----2


    //assigning formData to a form---3
    var eq=document.forms[1];
    var form=new FormData(eq);
    form.append("file",files[0]);
    //---3


    var SizeOfFile=files[0].size;
    var yt=SizeOfFile/1024;
    var ct=yt/1000;
    if(ct > 60) 
      window.alert("document>64mb cannot be uplaoded");
    else
    {
      var y=document.getElementById("demo");
      y.style.display="inline";
      y.style.visibility="visible";
      y.innerHTML=x;
    }
  }
  else
    window.alert("upload one file Only");
  event.target.style.border = "3px dotted grey";
  document.getElementById("FirstLine").style.display="inline";

}
```

```css
input#fileSelector {
  opacity:0;
  width:0.1px;
  height:0.1px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index=-1;
}
label#fileSelectorArea {
  background-color: lightGrey;
  opacity:0.4;
  padding:8px;
  outline:2px solid grey;
  margin-left:200px;
  bottom:15px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  top:7px;
}
label.hover {
  background-color:blue;
  opacity:1;
}
div#DragDropArea {
  margin-left:15px;
  width:300px;
  border:3px dotted grey;
  padding:80px;
  position:relative;
  top:50px;
}
label#Attachments {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:15px;
  top:130px;
}
div#FirstLine {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  margin-left:75px;
  opacity:0.7;
}
span#NextLine {
  top:40px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:50px;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<!--DOC_HANDLER FRAME--->


<div id="DragDropArea" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="dropHandler(event)" ondragleave="leavedrag(event)">
  <div id="FirstLine">
    <span>Drag Files here to attach</span>
    <br>
    <span id="NextLine">or</span>
  </div>
</div>
<label for="fileSelector" id="fileSelectorArea" onmouseover="hello()" onmouseleave="hi()">
  Select Files<input type="file" id="fileSelector" />
</label>
<input type="file" id="fileDoc" style="opacity:0" />
<div id="AppendFile" style="margin-left:15px;position:relative;top:70px;">
  <p id="demo" style="visibility:hidden"></p>
</div>
<p id="demor" style="visibility:hidden"></p>
<form id="ui">
</form>
```

When trying to assign the "event.dataTransfer.files" to the existing FileHandler ,while dropping the files to drag Area ,the ".files" object is not recognised by IE-11 browser.

I was trying to access the FileObject in other jsp in the Following way:

```js
function save()
{
  var t=null;
  if (parent.window.frames["DOC_HANDLER"]) {
    m_filename=parent.window.frames[2].document.getElementById("fileChooser");
    var ww=parent.window.frames[2].document.getElementById("ui");
    t=parent.window.frames[2].document.getElementById("filetype");
    var r=t.files[0];
    if(t==null)
      window.alert("drop a file first");
  }

  if(m_filename==="")
    window.alert("Please Upload a File");
```

```html
<!--frame[1] name=newdetail"-->
```

Is there any way that I could get the File-Handler object in the parent Frame's javascript function.I do not want to use AJAX upload of Form-Data since i need to send some other data along with File-Content in Parent JSP. Can Someone help on this?

Thank You.

Comment: _"I do not want to use AJAX upload of Form-Data since i need to send some other data along with File-Content"_ You can send additional information to server using `FormData.prototype.append()`. At `event.target.lastChild.files=files;` are you trying to assign a value to `<input type="file">` element `.files` property?

Comment: See also [How to work with FileList (from <input type=“file”>) in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580177/how-to-work-with-filelist-from-input-type-file-in-javascript)

Comment: @guest271314, Yes I tried appending other meta data to FormData() .It works fine but I have my entire meta-data existing in Other Page.And Yes I was trying to assign the .files property with `event.target.lastChild.files=files;`.Bu that also didnot help .So is there anyway that i could these `event.target.files` in parent page.

Comment: If `<iframe>` and parent `window` have same origin you can use `postMessage` to transfer the `Files` object to parent `window` from `iframe`.

Comment: @guest271314,I tried sending the object using `windows.postMessage('key',*,[object])` to the parent frame and to other window, but it didn't work .I suppose this wont work in IE-11.

Comment: Was able to post `File` using `window.postMessage()` at `drop` event by converting `File` to `ArrayBuffer` using `FileReader`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> //appending filehandler to target area and assign files to it---1      
> //IE restriction   
> event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById("fileDoc"));
> event.target.lastChild.files=files;
> ```

`<input type="file">` element `.files` references `FileList` object which is set to read-only. See [How to work with FileList (from <input type="file">) in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580177/how-to-work-with-filelist-from-input-type-file-in-javascript).

> Is there any way that I could get the File-Handler object in the
>   parent Frame's javascript function.

You can use `window.postMesaage()` to post `Blob URL` of dropped file or transfer the `File` object as an `ArrayBuffer` to `parent` `window`.

Post `Blob URL` as message

parent `window`

```
let url;
window.addEventListener("message", function handleMessage(event) {
  // check origin of event
  if (event.target.origin === "http://origin.def") {
    url = event.data;
    // do stuff with `Blob URL` of `File` from `iframe`
  }
});
```

`iframe` `window`

```
let url;
function handleDrop(e) {
  url = URL.createObjectURL(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
  window.parent.postMessage(url, window.parent.location.href));
}
```

Transfer `ArrayBuffer` representation of `File` as message

parent `window`

```
let url;
let type;
window.addEventListener("message", function handleMessage(event) {
  if (event.origin === "http://origin.def") {        
    if (typeof event.data === "string") {
      type = event.data;
    }
    if (event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer && type) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([event.data],{type:type}));
      console.log(url);
      // do stuff with `Blob URL` of `File` from `iframe`
    }
  }
}
```

`iframe` `window`

```
let reader = new FileReader();
function handleDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // post `File.type`
  window.parent.postMessage(
    e.dataTransfer.files[0].type
    , window.parent.location.href
  );
  reader.onload = function() {
    window.parent.postMessage(
      reader.result
      , window.parent.location.href
      , [reader.result]
    );
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
}
```