# Dynamically assigning a file to the file input field in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, csv, input

So I am aware that I can't create a form with a preset value on the input type=form due to file system security parameters put in place by browser vendors. However, is it at all possible to assign it a value from a file stored in the browser?

Here is the use case:

We are dynamically generating a .CSV file with Javascript based on user input into a table. I've seen quite a few tutorials on downloading the CSV as a file, but I would like to be able to send an email with the CSV as an attachment, and via the form supplied by HubSpot (our CRM provider), the best way to do that is to attach a file to the file input field.

**In summation:** Can I attach a .csv file that I've dynamically generated in the browser to a file input on a form with JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not possible to set `File` object at [`FileList`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#filelist-section) object referenced by `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element. `FileList` object is read only.

You can `.append()` one or more `File` objects to a `FormData` object and `POST` the `FormData` object to server. See [How to work with FileList (from <input type="file">) in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580177/how-to-work-with-filelist-from-input-type-file-in-javascript/38580250#38580250)