# Delete function in html upload form

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple upload form like this:

```
            <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Select XML to upload:</td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="files" size="50" multiple/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <div id="selectedFiles"></div>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="1" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>


    <script>
        var selDiv = "";

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

        function init() {
            document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
            selDiv = document.querySelector("#selectedFiles");
        }

        function handleFileSelect(e) {
            console.dir(e);

            if (!e.target.files)
                return;

            selDiv.innerHTML = "";

            var files = e.target.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var f = files[i];

                selDiv.innerHTML += f.name + "<button id='" + f.name + "'>  Delete: " + f.name + "</button><br/>";

            }

        }
    </script>
```

Form is able to show all data in actual select. I want implement delete function on my button `selDiv.innerHTML += f.name + "<button id='" + f.name + "'>  Delete: " + f.name + "</button><br/>";`.

The problem is that I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me?

Can somebody show me some code?

I think, best way is use some `onclick` event on my `button`. But how to delete one item from select list?

Comment: Are you trying to remove a `File` object from `FileList` object?

Comment: From <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="files" size="50" multiple/>

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to delete a `File` object from read-only [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object. You can add `File` objects to `FormData` object using `.append()`, then use `.delete()` to remove item from `FormData()` object by referencing the key in `FormData`; e.g.,

```
var data = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  data.append("file-" + i, files[i], files[i].name);
};
data.delete("file-0"); // delete `"file-0"` of `data`
```

then `POST` the `FormData` object to server.

You can alternatively add `File` objects to an `Array` and use `.splice()` to remove the item from the array, see [input file to array javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841147/input-file-to-array-javascript-jquery)

Comment: And how can I push variable `data` to my input form?

Comment: @hosledeh You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to `POST` `FormData` object to server

Comment: But I don't want to send data after remove one item. Just, I want update my input form.

Comment: It is not possible to set the `File` or `FileList` of `<input type="file">` element using `javascript` as `files` property of `<input type="file">` element is read-only. Instead of posting actual `<form>`, post `FormData` object which can include same data as included in `<form>`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously