# How to add multiple file input fields through 1 input file

Tags: javascript, jquery-file-upload

My system doesn't allow multiple file input, and I'm not using AJAX.

My situation is that I want to add images from 1 input file "multiple", and map them to a number of hidden file inputs. Is that possible?

In this link
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options
html

```
<form method="post" action="path">
    <input type="file" name="temp" id="temp" multiple>
    <input type="file" name="images" id="images" style="display: none">
    <input type="file" name="images2" id="images2" style="display: none">
    <input type="file" name="images3" id="images3" style="display: none">
    <input type="file" name="images4" id="images4" style="display: none">
    <input type="file" name="images5" id="images5" style="display: none">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#form').fileupload({
        paramName: ["images", "images2", "images3", "images4", "images5"],
        fileInput: $('#form input#temp'),
        replaceFileInput: false,
        change: function (e, data) {
                        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                            console.log('Selected file: ' + file.name);
                        });
                    }
    })
})
```

I've tried to set parameter "fileInput" to the temp file input and I set "paramName" to the array of the other file inputs, but its not working, and seems not to be used for that purpose.

Can it be done?

Comment: Are you trying to add `File` objects to `FileList` object? Does jQuery-File-Upload plugin use ajax? Can you include `html`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: See also [input file to array javascript/jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841147/input-file-to-array-javascript-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to replace each div image

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#divId').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

and have a clear image in place of each div img to be replaced..obviously tweak the code some for your amount of images. If there were a working fiddle I would have fully coded it.