# stop attaching files that size more than 5mb to multiple file input

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor

I developed custom multiple file upload feature like follows

[image]

this is the whole code for above module

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="file_count"></div>
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="FileUpload" multiple="multiple" />
<div id="upload_prev"></div>
```

**Script**

```
var fileCount = 0;

var showFileCount = function() {
  $('#file_count').text('# Files selected: ' + fileCount);
};

showFileCount();

$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
  $(this).parents('span').remove();
  fileCount -= 1;
  showFileCount();
})

$('#uploadFile').on('change', function() {

  var filename = this.value;
  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
  }
  var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
  {
    if (files[i].size < 5242880) 
    {
       $("#upload_prev").append('<span>' + '<div class="filenameupload">' + files[i].name + ' abc</div>' + '<p class="close" >X</p></span>');
    }
    else
    {
       alert("File size is more than 5MB");
       event.preventDefault();
       false;
    }
  }
  fileCount += files.length;
  showFileCount();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.filenameupload {
  width: 98%;
}

#upload_prev {
  border: thin solid #000;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 1.5em 1em;
}

#upload_prev span {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

I'm trying to stop files, that size more than 5mb attaching to this 'uploadFile' multiple file input,  using above code.

but it can 'append' div items properly and can't stop attaching files(size more than 5mb) to above 'uploadFile' multiple file input

How can I resolve this

**EDIT**

This is a ASP.NET MVC Application, this is how I'm getting files from backend

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult SomeAction(ModelClass model)
{
    var attchaedfiles = Request.Files;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to not upload files over 5MB?

Comment: @guest271314 yes I want to stop attaching them to this multiple file input

Comment: How are files uploaded to server?

Comment: Well since you don't know how large the files are before the user selects them, you can only react to it afterwards. And I don't think preventing the default event action is going to work in that it would remove the selected file again. So you can only alert the user that they have to remove that file again, and perform your check again afterwards on the next change event.

Comment: @guest271314 I think you''re proposing filter it in server side, actually I want to setup these files from client side, I'm getting these file in server side using following syntax `var attchaedfiles = Request.Files;`

Comment: @CBroe how can I remove that file, specifically if its more than 5mb from the list of files ?

Comment: You can not manipulate the selection of a file input via script, for security reasons. The user has to remove the file.

Comment: The alternative would be that you don't use one input with multiple attribute, but add file inputs that take one file each dynamically - then you could just remove a particular input field again, if the user chose a file that is to big.

Comment: @CBroe can mention resource or example

Comment: For what exactly?

Comment: @CBroe for the approach you mention in previous comment

Comment: What parts are unclear or you're having trouble with? How to dynamically create new input elements? Well you managed to create and append `span` elements in your code already (although creating invalid HTML, because `span` can not contain `div` or `p` elements), so you should be able to create and append other types of elements as well. How to remove an element via jQuery is something you can easily research yourself, if unknown. Whether you want to bind a change event handler to each created input field individually, or use _event delegation_ to "catch 'em all in one go", is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

`FileList` object referenced by `.files` property of `<input type="file">` element is read-only. You can use `.item()` method of `FileList` to to select a single `File` object at a specific index, though it is not possible to set or remove `File` object from `FileList` object. See [input file to array javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841147/input-file-to-array-javascript-jquery/).

You can use `FormData`, `FormData.prototype.append()`, `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` to send only files which meet `if` condition to server.

```
$('#uploadFile').on('change', function() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  var filename = this.value;
  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
  var count = 0;
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
  }
  var files = $('#uploadFile')[0].files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
  {
    if (files[i].size < 5242880) 
    {
       $("#upload_prev").append('<span>' + '<div class="filenameupload">' + files[i].name + ' abc</div>' + '<p class="close" >X</p></span>');
       fd.append("file-" + (count++), files[i])
    }
  }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "/path/to/server", true);
  request.send(fd);
  fileCount = Array.from(fd.keys()).length;
  showFileCount();
});
```

Comment: do i need to define "/path/to/server" here ?

Comment: @kez Yes, substitute path to server where file is uploaded. You could also attach `load`,  `error` handlers at `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: Does `javascript` at Answer not return expected result?

Comment: no I have no Idea to bind these validated result send thoes to above C# post method